# A question on integration by parts

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition, page 148...

> Observe
>   \begin{align}
> \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_t v_x \, dx dt &= -\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty wv_{tx} \, dx dt - \int_{-\infty}^\infty wv_x \, dx \vert_{t=0} \\
> &= \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_x v_{t} \, dx dt + \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_x v \, dx \vert_{t=0}
> \end{align}

For the first line, I believe the formula to the integration by parts was employed. (Please correct me if I'm mistaken.) But for the last step, may I ask how can we just move the subscript of $x$ from $v$ to $w$, in both the terms, and expect to remove the negative?

(Note: This step is part of proving the Lax-Oleinik formula as an integral solution to a certain PDE with initial conditions.)

Comment: Are we to assume compact support on $w$?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps I should note also that the mapping x↦w(x,t) is Lipschitz continuous from earlier proofs (thus, absolutely continuous). Similar with t↦w(x,t) -- absolutely continuous for each x∈R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $w,v$ are in the necessary spaces you are correct about the first line.
Remember that the general idea for IBP is
$$
\int_S u v' \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_{\partial S} uv \, \mathrm{d} \mu - \int_S u'v \, \mathrm{d} \mu
$$
and that the first integral vanishes as long as either $v$ or $u$ has compact support (i.e. the functions are in the correct space).

So now consider
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_t v_x \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}^{t\to\infty} \,\mathrm{d} x - \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w v_{xt} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t \\
& = & - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0} \, \mathrm{d}x  - \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w v_{xt} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Here we are integrating by parts in the $t$, and the second equality comes from an assumption that $w$ has compact support in $t$. Now let's do this again but this time in the $x$ integral:
$$
- \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0} \, \mathrm{d}x  - \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w v_{xt} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t \\
= - \left. \left. wv \right|_{t=0} \right|_{x\to -\infty}^{x \to \infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left. w_x v \right|_{t=0} \, \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^{\infty} \left. w v_t \right|_{x\to-\infty}^{x\to\infty} \, \mathrm{d}t + \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_x v_t \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t \\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w_x v \right|_{t=0} \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w_x v_t \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t
$$
where the last equality follows from the assumption that $w$ has compact support in $x$.

Comment: Note that you'll also need some derivatives of some sort here, i.e. $w,v \in \mathcal{C}^1$ or $w,v \in H^1$

Comment: Thanks for providing your answer rather quickly. If it's okay with you though, I plan to take a careful look at this later, as right now I need to get some sleep -- it's late in the night in my timezone (which is PDT).

Comment: @glace no problem! I'm central, actually just woke up :D

Comment: For the work of $\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w_t v_x \, dx dt$, the first step is using the integration by parts formula which I understand. In between the next two steps, you asserted that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}^{t\to\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}$$ That is what I still have trouble understanding; can you explain how the negative sign comes out when you simply remove the "$t \rightarrow \infty$"?

Comment: @glace well note that I assert
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}^{t \to \infty} = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}
$$
and this follows since the side becomes
$$
\lim_{b \to \infty} w(x,b) v_x(x,b) - w(x,0) v_x(x,0)
$$
but this first term drops out due to compact support, thus leaving
$$
\left. w v_x \right|_{t=0}
$$
which is then inside the integral